# No keyboard layout indicator (text) in the notification area

Tags: 10.10, gnome, keyboard-layout, notification-area

This question seems to have a long history, but I was somehow unable to find a straightforward answer to it. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 with two or three keyboard layouts (US, RU, DE). When I first added additional layouts, there appeared a 3-letter code of the layout at the keyboard icon in the notification area, like this (this is an image from [another post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaYiQ.png)):

[image: Keyboard layout indication]

However, after some weeks of working with Ubuntu, I now have just the keyboard icon, no layout code:

[image]

I've no idea why it has disappeared. How can I get it back? :)

---

Just installed Ubuntu 11.04. In a fresh installation with two layouts, I again have an indicator without doing anything for it. Puzzled.

[image: Screenshot of layout indicator]

BTW, in the login screen the layout indicated to the right from the password field is unreadable with the "flag icons" suggested as a solution above. With the standard layout indicator, the letters are shown, which is better. So any suggestions as to why the standard layout indicator may disappear are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slick solution: Language Flags Ubuntu Mono Dark 
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+Ubuntu+Mono+Dark+11.04?content=140209

Also mono light, faenza. 
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Ubuntu+Mono+Light?content=134483

I think they look much nicer.

1. Extract to ~/.icons/flags
2. Run `gconftool-2 --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/indicator/showFlags true`

Comment: I like this solution (a bit misleading name 'Flag' though, since I want to have letters, and that's exactly what the linked collections provide). However, after I've done this, the keyboard icon is now replaced with a red  backslashed circle (a symbol for 'no icon found'). I definitely have the svg files in ~/.icons/flags and /apps/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/indicator/showFlags is checked. If I uncheck it then after logging out and logging in the red 'no icon' icon is replaced back with the keyboard icon without the layout code.

Answer (score 0):

Having found no better answer, I just played around. Looks like the flag icons are only used by the Indicator Applet. This doesn't solve the original question (why the keyboard layout is not shown in the *notification area*) but the result looks well. I also like the sound control icon of the Indicator Applet more than the standard one from the notification area.

A nice side effect of using the Indicator Applet is that the typing break icon, which used to be the red backslashed circle (i.e. 'no icon found') with the standard keyboard icon in the notification area is now a green or red bar, depending on the status.

[image]